# How much is "k'dei l'chametz"?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, bitul-batel-null, maseches-orla

How much is "enough sourdough to ferment"? [*Orla* 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Orlah.2.6) refers to it as a qualitative measure, independent of the 200:1 ratio which is the quantitative measure that would render the sourdough indelible even if it didn't have the aforementioned potency.

So what is "*k'dei l'chametz*"? The amount of material needed to leaven some known but unstated mass of dough? The amount needed to activate *this* mass of dough? Some part of this mass of dough? Surely there are degrees of fermentation possible ranging from the infinitesimal up to. . .[extremely fluffy](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2019/02/09/food/meteoric-rise-nogamis-fluffy-shokupan/)?

Comment: Enough to achieve the degree of fermentation that is chametz (pale with cracks forming or whatever that is that only shows up after at least 18 minutes under ordinary circumstances). Chametz is a specific level of fermentation.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56987/is-chimutz-a-wholly-physical-phenomenon